# get images after comparisonApi and store data in database with matched names

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-rekognition

hi on aws I have two folders  1  is boss where all images of boss are and indexed using indexfacesApi  now I want to modify this code to use all images from folder 'Event' and store in new table . like  After camparision I got 3 pictures of  boss name myboss

so In new database entry will be

image1   myboss
image4   myboss

and for other bosses as well same case . ATM using this

```
import boto3
import io
from PIL import Image

rekognition = boto3.client('rekognition', region_name='eu-west-1')
dynamodb = boto3.client('dynamodb', region_name='eu-west-1')

image = Image.open("group1.jpeg")
stream = io.BytesIO()
image.save(stream,format="JPEG")
image_binary = stream.getvalue()


response = rekognition.search_faces_by_image(
        CollectionId='family_collection',
        Image={'Bytes':image_binary}                                       
        )

for match in response['FaceMatches']:
    print (match['Face']['FaceId'],match['Face']['Confidence'])

    face = dynamodb.get_item(
        TableName='family_collection',  
        Key={'RekognitionId': {'S': match['Face']['FaceId']}}
        )

    if 'Item' in face:
        print (face['Item']['FullName']['S'])
    else:
        print ('no match found in person lookup')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This example can help you, this will fetch all images in your **Event/** folder and then compare with your **collection-id** in rekognition and if match is found , then that image will be saved in new folder **results** and the names retrieved from collection related DB will be stored in a new table **results** of dynamodb

```
from __future__ import print_function

import boto3
import io
import uuid
import urllib
from PIL import Image
import datetime
from pprint import pprint


def lambda_handler(event, context):
    rekognition = boto3.client('rekognition')
    dynamodb = boto3.client('dynamodb')
    s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
    s3client=boto3.client('s3')

    Bucket=s3.Bucket('ais-django');
    obj = s3.Object('ais-django','Event/')

    i = datetime.datetime.now()
    ptr= i.strftime("%d-%m-%y     %H:%M:%S (UTC)")

    for obj in Bucket.objects.filter(Prefix='Event/'):
        filename=obj.key
        if filename.endswith(".jpeg") or filename.endswith(".jpg") or filename.endswith(".png"):
            key=str(filename)
            bucket='ais-django'
            print(key)

            local = '/tmp/'+ptr+'.jpeg'

            s3client.download_file(bucket,key, local)

            image = Image.open(local)
            stream = io.BytesIO()
            image.save(stream,format="JPEG")

            image_binary = stream.getvalue()
            response = rekognition.detect_faces(
                Image={'Bytes':image_binary}
                )


            all_faces=response['FaceDetails']

            boxes = []
            image_width = image.size[0]
            image_height = image.size[1]

            for face in all_faces:
                box=face['BoundingBox']
                x1 = int(box['Left'] * image_width) * 0.9
                y1 = int(box['Top'] * image_height) * 0.9
                x2 = int(box['Left'] * image_width + box['Width'] * image_width) * 1.10
                y2 = int(box['Top'] * image_height + box['Height']  * image_height) * 1.10
                image_crop = image.crop((x1,y1,x2,y2))

                stream = io.BytesIO()
                image_crop.save(stream,format="JPEG")
                image_crop_binary = stream.getvalue()

                response = rekognition.search_faces_by_image(
                    CollectionId='family_collection',
                    Image={'Bytes':image_crop_binary}
                    )

                if len(response['FaceMatches']) > 0:

                    for match in response['FaceMatches']:
                        face = dynamodb.get_item(
                            TableName='family_collection',
                            Key={'RekognitionId': {'S': match['Face']['FaceId']}}
                            )
                        if 'Item' in face:
                            person = face['Item']['FullName']['S']
                            print(person);
                            ktr='results/'+person+'.jpg'
                            s3client.upload_file(local, 'ais-django', ktr,ExtraArgs={'ContentType': 'image/jpeg','ACL': 'public-read'})
                            dynamodb.put_item(
                                TableName='results',
                                Item={
                                    'image': {'S': key},
                                    'FullName': {'S': person},
                                    'date': {'S': ptr}
                                }
                            )                               
                else:
                    print('null')
```

Replace **bucketname**, **collection-id** name , **dynamodb table names** with yours